# Ненаголошені голосні у словах іншомовного походження

Tags: правопис, орфографія, spelling

Яким правилом слід керуватись для перевірки ненаголошених голосних у словах іншомовного походження?

[Правопис](http://pravopys.net/#search=90-91) містить доволі прості норми передачі голосних для іменників: у більшості випадків `i/y` переходить у `і/и/ї`, в той час як `е` переходить в `е/є`. Це правило підходить для перевірки другого голосного у слові "інгр**e**дієнт" ("ingr**e**dient").

Але це правило не стосується дієслів та дієприкметників. Наприклад, яким має бути другий голосний у дієприкметнику, похідному від слова "корекція" ("corr**e**ction")?

Зустрічаєтсья як варіант "кор**е**гуючий" ([Словник.ua](http://www.slovnyk.ua/?swrd=%EA%EE%F0%E5%E3%F3%FE%F7%E8%E9&x=0&y=0)) так і "кор**и**гуючий" ([bank.gov.ua](http://bank.gov.ua/control/uk/publish/article?art_id=24491081)): "*Національний банк України затвердив розміри кор**и**гуючих коефіцієнтів за видами активів*"

Comment: Слід користуватися порадами "Українського правопису" щодо передачі голосних у словах іншомовного походження, вони є досить повними. А також звертатись до академічних тлумачного або орфографічного словників. Наголошуваність при передачі голосних не грає ролі, важливим є після яких букв або в яких звукосполученнях вживається голосна. Слова "корегуючий" і "коригуючий" на мій погляд є однаково неправильними. Правильно - "корегувальний".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Словник української мови каже, що

[КОРЕГУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/koreghuvaty), ую, уєш, недок., перех.

> 1. військ. Вносити поправки в наведення гармат, спостерігаючи їх стрільбу з певних пунктів. Поручик Туманов, щоб було зручніше
>      корегувати стрільбу, услід за піхотою теж кинувся з телефоністами до
>      першої лінії (Петро Панч, I, 1956, 136).
> 2. книжн., друк. **Те саме, що коректувати** 1, 2. Можна признати рацію моєму бажанню ***корегувати*** самій, бо таки автор завжди має
>      гостріше око (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 278); В Адаменка був гострий
>      розум, план того бою цілком постав у його голові, я лише ***корегував*** і
>      переводив на практичні рейки (Юрій Яновський, II, 1958, 253).

*Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 4, 1973. — Стор. 286.*

В той же час, в [Українському правописі 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil0.htm) у передмові читаємо:

> Правопис — система, що саморозвивається. Тому цей процес необхідно
>   відстежувати, упорядковувати, **коригувати**. Невипадково всі країни
>   рано чи пізно стикаються з необхідністю **відкоригувати** правопис,
>   оскільки відбуваються зміни у суспільстві, у мовній системі; мова, як
>   живий організм, нарощується новими словами, видозмінюється і, ясна
>   річ, набуває нових властивостей, які обов’язково треба побачити й
>   зафіксувати.

Очевидно, це не відповідь на запитання, а радше підтвердження того, що питання дійсно не унормоване.

Comment: Пропоную дати новішу інформацію з СУМ-20. Там вже "коригувати" основна форма.