# То "Арістотель" чи "Аристотель"?

Tags: власні-назви, правопис, орфографія, іноземні-імена

Залежно від джерела зустрічаю різне написання імені цього давньогрецького вченого - "Ар**і**стотель" та "Ар**и**стотель". Більш поширеним варіантом написання є через "і".

У зв'язку з цим питання - якщо написання Арістотель є правильним, то чому ім'я давньогрецького царя з абсолютно ідентичним грецьким коренем "αριστο", пишеться, як Аристократ, а не Арістократ? Де логіка?

Comment: Логіки нема,  є тільки історія запозичення та вживання слів. Ось наприклад - New York i New Orleans українською **Нью** Йорк і **Новий** Орлеан.

Comment: Related: http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/515/

Comment: Related: http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/334

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Відповідно до вимог [чинного правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90), правильний варіант - Арістотель, бо [правило дев'ятки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) не поширюється на власні назви. Ініційований правописом 1999 року "Аристотель" не прижився: зрештою, навіть "[скрипниківка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81)" закликає "завсігди писати **і**" після приголосних у власних назвах іншомовного походження.

Щодо Аристократа, логіки справді немає, бо загальна назва *аристократ* і *аристократія* за правилом дев'ятки мають писатися через "и", але чому у власній назві не зробили навпаки, як мало бути б за правилом? Можливо, щоб не змінювати корінь (це ж ім'я походить від загальної назви, а не навпаки), але все одно виглядає дивно. Приблизно так, як "ортодоксальна орфографія".

Comment: Palacsinta, а Ви впевнені, що Аристократа (власну назву) «не зробили навпаки, як мало бути б за правилом»? Бо того ж Арістотеля різні словники (в т.ч. видані після 2000) пишуть по-різному (он в [ULIF](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) — Аристотель; у Вікіпедії [довго думали, і вирішили](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=16961592), що то помилка). Може, й Аристократа деякі («більш правильні») словники пишуть як «Арістократ»?

Comment: @Sasha, ось примітка з чинного правопису: "власні імена, що перетворилися в назви предметів і явищ, тобто стали загальними іменами, пишуться за правилами правопису загальних назв іншомовного походження: ди́зель (хоч Ді́зель)" і вона вбиває будь-які спроби знайти логіку, бо так само мало бути аристократ (хоч Арістократ). Здається, власна назва просто закріпилася в мові до введення Смаль-Стоцьким правила дев'ятки і ніхто не захотів нічого змінювати.

Comment: Я не про те. Те, що загальні імена можуть писатися не як власні (а за правилом 9) — це зрозуміло. Я про те, чи впевнені Ви, що Ар_стократ (як власна назва) пишеться саме «Ар**и**стократ», а не «Ар**і**стократ»? Бо те, що якісь джерела пишуть «Аристократ», ще не означає, що всі так пишуть чи що так правильно.

Comment: Щодо Ар(і/и)стократа - тут (як на мене) питання - чи закріпилася ця власна назва. Можливо що ні, оскільки, як мені відомо, з перекладами грецьких текстів на українську є проблема (принаймні видань творів Арістотеля українською не існує).

Comment: @Artemix, не існує?! А як же "Поетика", "Політика", "Нікомахова етика"?  І комедії Арістофана теж перекладені, але от Аристократа таки всюди пишуть через "и."

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Не на затвердження, просто хочу подїлитися</sup>

Очевидно, шчо лоґіка теми — [виняток 9](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) — а ось далї лоґіки нема, спробуємо розібратися з наступною непоганою статтею:

**[Непояснене/непоясненне „правило дев’ятки“](https://r2u.org.ua/node/117)**

*Там доволї детально все розписано: давнина, думки, приклади инших словʼянських народів, вирішення тощо. Спробую скоротити.*

**Думки**

- Завше писати *и*, бо такий український звичай (спірно).
- Залишити »як є« деякі вказуть на тотожність польського звичаю.
- Розширити чи зменшити — тут вистачає варіянтів.

Цебто питання всього цього — зберегти чужомовне звучання і при цьому українську фонетіку.

**Рішення**

Коли згадати инше питання, а саме про [тверду **і** й мʼяку **ї**](/a/3065/585). Цебто подїбне правило б спокійно розповсюджувало на чужомовні запозичення і під корінь знищувало винятка 9. На прикладї:

- *ситі* (неголодні), *сіті* (місто, *с* тут тверде), *сїтї* (*сїтки*, *с* тут м’яке)
- *тік* (місце, *т* — тверде), *тик*, *тїк* (*текти*, *т* — м’яке)

*Очевидно, що тут було б ‚Арістотель‘ і ‚арістократ‘.*